# How do I set correct name resolution in dnsmasq on a per-client basis?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

Here's the story:

On my local network I'm using a Raspberry Pi with dnsmasq for name resolution and DHCP. Our household consists of two adults & two kids, and I'm looking at restricting internet access for the kids via OpenDNS.

I've *almost* got this working correctly, by starting from [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/509388/245703). Essentially, what I'm doing is "tagging" the kids' devices with a keyword ("kids"), and associating an alternate DNS server (OpenDNS) with that tag, via the following:

```
# regular DNS for most devices
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.111.11,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

# restricted DNS for kids (two OpenDNS IP addresses, and my local DNS server)
dhcp-option=tag:kids,option:dns-server,208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220,192.168.1.11
```

```
# IP reservations for kids devices
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,set:kids,192.168.1.190
YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY,set:kids,192.168.1.191
```

This works: the kids' devices hit OpenDNS' servers for name resolution and are blocked from inappropriate sites.

But the problem is that the kids can no longer access hosts on our local network. This means that, for example, they can't access our local Minecraft server or file shares. I have tried switching the order of the DNS server and placing our local DNS server first in the order for the kids, but this disables the OpenDNS servers.

I've tried to think of a solution to this and the only thing I've come up with is setting up a second DNS server on another Raspberry Pi, but this means duplicating a lot of configuration that I don't want to keep track of.

**How can I configure DNSMasq to properly resolve local addresses with different "external" DNS servers for two distinct sets of clients?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid such a configuration isn't possible, you'd need to run a second internal DNS to be able to control which upstream DNS server is used. You can however set up a conditional forwarder on the secondary server so that you don't need to configure everything twice:

1. Configure a secondary DNS server for "restricted access"
2. For illustrative purposes, let's say that your internal zone on your primary DNS server is `homedomain.local`. Configure a conditional forwarder on the secondary DNS server to forward all requests for `homedomain.local` to your primary DNS server.

This way any queries for let's say `minecraftserver.homedomain.local` gets sent to your internal DNS servers, but queries for any other domains gets sent to OpenDNS.